# Cannot connect Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 SM-T705 to computer vis usb

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung

I'm trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 SM-T705 with Android 4.4.2 to computer via usb - but there's no effect. Fun thing is that I was able to do it a week ago.
Connection of flash card to usb port also fails - device doesn't appear in Settings->Device list.
What can I do to detect problem?

Comment: Does it charge when you plug a usb charger in?

Comment: Or, another question might be, does it charge when you plug it into the computer port?  Make sure the hardware (cable and the port) is working before installing software.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, currently fixed it by downloading
"All Drivers for Android" application by hexamob from the Play Store.

Open up the application and then plug in your usb.
This will either download drivers or you will see
the usb connection on notification bar.

hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My PC could not recognise my USB port from my SAMSUNG GALAXY TAB S 8.4 TM-705

My external SD CARD inserted in the tablet could not be recognized by the tablet drive system, so, I came here to read about and later

I found "USB OTG HELPER" on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg

and it worked instantly showing off my tablet name on MY DESKTOP list of drives on my pc.

PORT USB CARTE EXTERNE PAS DE CONNEXION PC ORDINATEUR PAS RECONNU GALAXY TAB S 8.4 TM-705 KITKAT

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:

1. Connect your Galaxy Tab using a USB cable to your PC.
2. If you now click on "Computer" the various drives will show but at this stage your Galaxy Tab will not appear.
3. Right-click on "Computer" and click on "Properties", then select "Device Manager".
4. Now you will see "Galaxy Tab" under Portable Devices, but it will have a small yellow exclamation mark in the icon to indicate that the device is not functioning. Don't worry.
5. Right-click on the icon and select "Update Driver Software".
6. Now click on "Search Automatically for Updated Driver Software" and you are done. You need to be connected to the internet during the process.
7. Now open "Computer" on your PC and you will see Galaxy Tab as one of the Portable Drives. If you have already installed a SD Card in your Galaxy Tab, this will show up and you can perform all the usual operations to transfer, delete, add, and more, from PC to Tablet.

Make sure that the SD card has been correctly formatted after you insert it into your Galaxy device.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDE TO ENABLE DEVICE RUNNING OF APPLICATION

Note: I tried this on my phone.

Note: Follow Google's Android instructions to better follow the steps below.

1. After downloading Android Studio, update it.
2. Install Google USB driver: Go to *SDK Manager* -> *SDK Tools* -> tick *Google USB driver* -> click *Apply*.
3. Plug in your device.
4. Go to *Computer*, right-click -> select *Manage*.
5. Choose your device, right-click -> select *Update Driver* -> choose manually.
6. Select browse. It is found at your `SDK path\extras\google\usb_driver`.
7. If you don't know your SDK path, go to SDK Manager to find it written. Look for Android SDK location.
8. Click *Next*.
9. Go to your device, go to settings. Click *Developer Options*. Click *Enable USB debugging*.
10. Return, click *Run*.
11. Choose your device.
12. Enable adb integration if requested.
13. To enable it, go to *Tools* -> *Android* -> click the checkbox beside *Enable adb integration*.